# VB.NET 2005, Serial port, dispose problem, Windows CE

Tags: windows, vb.net, windows-ce, serial-port, dispose

I write program for Windows CE that should work with Serial ports. I use object `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`. Everything works well but when I close program and open it again, I receive error: Port is in use! At the end I write:

```
port.close()
port.dispose()
```

And If I add this:

```
System.GC.collect()
```

.. than everything begins to work

But problem is that computer gets stuck when garbage collector is called for each port. If I tried to use collector somewhere else, it doesnt "collect" ports and they look like used if program starts again.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Very late comment but you can try with `using (SerialPort p = new SerialPort())`. This will close and dispose the object automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that an object that owns the port object is not disposed or still maintains a reference. That would explain why after system.gc.collect() it works.

Comment: I understand this. But why doesnt collector work when I use it as the latest command of my program? My program contains a Module and Sub Main() in it. At the end of it I run the collector but ports are still open :(

Comment: I maybe found a solution. VB probably doesn't work with objects as I would expect in OOP. So I manualy destroy all ports at the end of Main() method. But as I'm undestanding VB.net and Visual Studio more and more, I like it less and less :( ... for example Abstract forms are a good story :)

Comment: "VB probably doesn't work with objects as I would expect in OOP"
I don't think it VB, but the .net framework. And also Windows CE adds another layer.

Comment: "At the end of it I run the collector but ports are still open".
The answer by ctacke may be more right than the dispose stuff, although both issues can be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential possibilities here.  First, just because you call Close, it doesn't mean the port is physically released - this is true even in C. It depends on the state of the UART and a whole lot on how the actual driver was written.  It may take time from the call to Close to the actual driver releasing the port.  This, I believe, is what you're actually seeing becasue you're actually manually calling close rather than waiting for the Finalizer to destroy your Port instance and implicitly close it - this would take even longer.

Of course this assumes that your Close call is actually being run.  If it's not, then you need to understand how object Finalization works in managed code.  This has nothing to do with OOP, it has to do with how memory is managed.  When an object does out of scope and has no more roots (references) it's available for collection, but that doesn't mean that it's immediately released.  In fact it can be quite some time before the finalizer runs, especially if the app continues to run.

Answer (score 0):

How long are you waiting between closing it and opening it? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.close.aspx#remarksToggle):

> The best practice for any application
>   is to wait for some amount of time
>   after calling the **Close** method before
>   attempting to call the Open method, as
>   the port may not be closed instantly.

Comment: Hello. Time delays were not important. In program I can call `port.open() port.close()  port.dispose() system.GC.collect()`

Comment: Hello. Time delays were not important. In program I can call `port.open() port.close()  port.dispose() system.GC.collect()` in "row" and it works. Problem is that program can not call destructor of this port where I use dispose() and collect(). That is the problem. I think it can be due to fact that my program has no main Class but a main Module. So I call destructor manualy at the end of Module and it works now.